# Where can you find an Ice stone in Pokemon X&Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Where can you find an ice stone in Pokemon X&Y?

Comment: Are you asking the about an [Ice Stone](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ice_Stone) or an [Ice Rock](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ice_Rock)? Ice Stones weren't released until Sun/Moon

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for the method of evolving Eevee into Glaceon, you are looking for the **Ice Rock**. The Ice Stone was not introduced until Sun and Moon as a means of evolving Alolan Sandshrew into Alolan Sandslash and Alolan Vulpix into Alolan Ninetales. These Pokemon are not available in Pokemon X or Pokemon Y, and neither is the Ice Stone.

The Ice Rock in Pokemon X&Y can be found within the Frost Cavern north of  Dendemille Town. You will need Surf to access the Ice Rock.

Answer (score 0):

There are no Ice Stones in X and Y.